# How do Ledger hardware wallet signatures differ from web3.eth.personal.sign?

Tags: metamask, ledger-nano-s

I have an Ethereum Dapp, which requires the user to sign a transaction to prove their identity. The app uses `web3.eth.personal.sign(nonce, coinbase)...` to sign a nonce generated in my back end.

It seems that signing with only Metamask, and signing with Ledger Nano on Metamask produce different hashes. So my question is:

**Is there a difference in how ledger signs transactions compared to web3.eth.personal.sign?**

Comment: Having this same problem. My Nano X is producing a signature that I can't verify locally. I can make transactions on ethereum, but for whatever reason when I try to write code to verify the javascript + mm + ledger generated signature, on the server side (php), it fails to verify. Something to do with the recovery value (last byte)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my Nano S. Did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ledger produces vrs signatures with a canonical `v` value of  {0,1}, while Ethereum's `ecrecover` call only accepts a non-standard `v` value of {27,28}. More on that [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19751#issuecomment-504900739).

Metamask handles this internally when signing directly through it without going through a Ledger, since it uses `ecsign` that [normalizes the v value for Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/f51bfcab9e5505dfed4819ef1336f9fc00a12c3d/src/signature.ts#L38). But when signing a message on a Ledger and then relay the resulting signature to Metamask, the `v` value is still going to be {0,1}.

For UI developers, here is where web3 libs shine. If we look into how ethers.js implements this, we could see that its implementation for [`splitSignature`](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/bf0b468490cb293cd916e4fff06e0909273719e6/packages/bytes/src.ts/index.ts#L333) manipulates a given signature's `v` value and normalizes it for Ethereum.

Answer (score 4):

I have this same problem and fixed it by replacing the v inside ledger signature curve:

```
def adapt_ledger(vrs):
  new_v = vrs[0]
  if new_v == 0:
    new_v = 27
  if new_v == 1:
    new_v = 28
  return (new_v, vrs[1], vrs[2])
```

Somehow ledger used 0 and 1 instead of 27-31.

I lost the source to this solution but I found it in a discussion somewhere.
Hope it helps.